# Xcode Auto Layout, label next to Switch

Tags: xcode, autolayout

Having struggles trying to get the following view to work across devices, this is just one of many of my auto-layout issues. I have some text next to a UISwitch, on devices that are large enough I am happy for the text to be on a single line but on smaller devices the text can be split across multiple lines, I just can't get it to work correctly, it either appears like the screenshot or somewhere else messed up no matter what constraints I try to apply.

The middle image is iPhone 7.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what how it's messed up?

Comment: Do you want the text to be as far across the screen until the switch is pushing up against the right edge then wrap once it shouldn't push the switch any further?

Comment: I want the text and switch to be aligned horizontally, I want the switch to be as close to the text as possible, on the iPad there is enough room for the text to be on a single line and for them the switch to be next to it. On the iPhone SE on the left, I want it to appear something like the iPhone 7 in the middle.

Comment: @JackBrown It is definitely possible, it's hard to express in words what it's like, but I'll try to whip up a sample to make a formal answer later. As a short summary for now, here's the constraints you'd want: leading on text field to super, trailing from text to leading switch, trailing switch to superview should be a greater than constraint so that it can't be pushed beyond the edge, and then similar constraints in the y axis. What you don't want is a height constraint on the text field. That should really be enough, there might be small tweaks for compression resistance, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but it is something I encountered myself recently.

In the storyboard, you should set the label's horizontal `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to 749.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the trailing side of the switch is not constrained to align with the trailing side of the text field and other UI elements. Also make sure there is no constraint for the width of the text, as this is what will stretch.